# Getting error "There is already an object named 'EventCategories' in the database" when I run EF Core code-first migration script

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> options) : base(GetConnectionString())
    {
        //Database.Migrate();
    }

    private static DbContextOptions GetConnectionString()
    {
        var connectionString = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build().GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["DefaultConnection"];
        return SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), connectionString).Options;
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EventCategory> EventCategories { get; set; }
}
```

I have already created database manually in SQL Server. Now I want to run code-first migration script using EF Core.

I have tried these two commands:

```
Add-Migration MigrationForTest -context TestDbContext
update-database -Context TestDbContext
```

But I am getting this error:

> There is already an object named 'EventCategories' in the database.

Can you please help me - how to solve this error?

I want to now run code first migration script to sync modal to database tables using EF Core.

Comment: Migrations are about history of changes. It's not clear from your question why this table is already there. In other words: what happed to the database before what you describe here?

Comment: It means there is already a table called `EventCategories` in your database, I am not sure if you want to create a new database with `EventCategories` table or just update data in `EventCategories` table

Comment: @XinranShen i need to update EventCategories table with existing database

Comment: Please refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75971031/getting-error-there-is-already-an-object-named-eventcategories-in-the-databas)